# using ANT_OPTS to affect target java app

Tags: java, linux, ant

I have a 2gig linux 64bit OS.  I am using ant 1.7.1 and jdk 1.6_31.  I have a simple app that prints that asks for the size of the Maximum java heap and prints it.  I am using export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx64M" but when I run my little application with ant target in build.xml, it reports 446Meg.

```
<target name="askmem">
    <java
        fork="true"
        classname="com.stagirite.test.AskMemory"
        classpathref="project.classpath">

        <classpath path="${build.dir}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

I must be doing something wrong?  (I discovered from stackoverflow that with this JVM, the default heap is 1/4 total memory, which is what is happening, rather than the value I specified in ANT_OPTS.

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forking the Java anyway, so even if `ANT_OPTS` *did* affect the `java` task, I don't think they'd transfer to it. `ANT_OPTS` is for ant itself.

If you want to control the JVM used by the forked `java` task, use nested `<jvmargs>` elements.